# Ubuntu 16.10 Server MariaDB (MySql) open_file_limit won't go higher than 16364

Tags: mysql, ulimit

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.10 (yakkety yak) with MariaDB 10.x and experience the very same issue as https://serverfault.com/questions/791729/ubuntu-16-04-server-mysql-open-file-limit-wont-go-higher-than-65536 with one exception, my open file limits is 16364

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep mysql)/limits | grep files
Max open files            16364                16364                files
grep -Ri 'open_files_limit' /etc/mysql/
/etc/mysql/my.cnf:open_files_limit = 1024000
/etc/mysql/my.cnf:open_files_limit  = 1024000
```

and

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max 3269904
su mysql --shell /bin/bash --command "ulimit -n" 1024000
```

I've searched a lot, and followed this guide, but nothing is changing the "Max Open Files" limit at all :(

Is there somebody who know the answer, or might be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @jerichorivera who wrote the answser here https://serverfault.com/a/833909

> 16K is the limit for LimitNOFILE for MariaDB, so you might want to
>   increase that in the systemd service definition. For more details
>   check this page: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/systemd/